# Tailwind CSS - make image in flex bigger

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want to move a picture/row down using Tailwind CSS, in order to achieve this kind of image gallery: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmPng.png

Here is what I have
tried:

```
    <section class="overflow-hidden text-gray-700">
        <div class="">
          <div class="flex flex-wrap ">
            <div class="flex flex-wrap w-2/3">
              <div class="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                <img alt="gallery" class="block object-cover object-center w-full h-full rounded-lg"
                  src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(70).webp">
              </div>
              <div class="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                <img alt="gallery" class="block object-cover object-center w-full h-full rounded-lg"
                  src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(72).webp">
              </div>
              <div class="w-full p-1 md:p-2">
                <img alt="gallery" class="block object-cover object-center w-full h-full rounded-lg"
                  src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(73).webp">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-wrap w-1/3">
              <div class="w-full p-1 md:p-2">
                <img alt="gallery" class="block object-cover object-center w-full h-full rounded-lg"
                  src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(74).webp">
              </div>
              <div class="w-full p-1 md:p-2">
                <img alt="gallery" class="block object-cover object-center w-full h-full rounded-lg"
                  src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(75).webp">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-wrap w-2/3">
                <div class="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                  <img alt="gallery" class="block object-cover object-center w-full h-full rounded-lg"
                    src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(70).webp">
                </div>
                <div class="w-1/2 p-1 md:p-2">
                  <img alt="gallery" class="block object-cover object-center w-full h-full rounded-lg"
                    src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(72).webp">
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the `grid` classes instead of `flex` for this purpose. Then you can use row-span and col-span, which makes it quite easy to achieve the grid that is in the example in your question.

[Here is an example in the tailwind playground.](https://play.tailwindcss.com/CqaKjQ6NSh)

See [this video](https://youtu.be/b-hrxkgkG-s) of TailwindLabs.

Hope this helps.